# How to update UITableViewCell drawing

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, uitableview, cell

My app displays some news in a `UITableView`. For each news-topic, the background color of the `UITableViewCell` is different (added a `UIView` in my custom cell).

So far, it works. But If I press on a `UIBarButton` to deselect one news-category, the content changes, **but the background stays the same as before**.

The color does not change, because **the cell does not reload again after button click**.

Any ideas?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can set the color for the cell in (as per your logic):

`- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView willDisplayCell:(UITableViewCell *)cell forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath`

This will make sure the color is set every time the cell is displayed.

Comment: Jep. Worked. Thank you. Nice method, never used it. :)

Answer (score 0):

In your `cellForRowAtIndexPath` method, make sure that you're setting the color of the `UITableViewCell`.

Also, use `[tableView reloadData];`

Comment: I do this by checking the type and then setting it using a `switch`-method. I also use `reloadData`. The __data__ is reloaded properly, but __not__ the appearance of the cells.

Comment: since the color of the cells remains the same, even after the data's changed, I have a feeling that you're not setting the color every time the table reloads.